# Create a node and assign it the sum of a column of the table in Cypher Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-3.1

I am trying to figure out how to implement the OLAP operation Roll-up in Cypher.
I am stuck with finding how to create a node and then assign it the sum of a column of a table in Cypher. More particularly, I am trying to achieve this result : 
[Code result [EDITED]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILORn.png)
With this code I am obtaining the result as seen in the picture :

```
MATCH(p:Product)
WITH sum(p.unitsInStock) as SommeUnits, p.supplierID as Supplier, p.reorderLevel as ReordLevel
CREATE(reord:Product {productName : "TotalReord", unitsInStock : SommeUnits})
RETURN ReordLevel,Supplier, SommeUnits
ORDER BY ReordLevel
```

Relationships : Supplier-[:SUPPLIES]->(Product)
Attributs of Product : unitsInStock, productName, productId, unitsInOrder, supplierID

The problem is that this code is not working properly because it generates not just one node but multiples, and the result that I get is obtained only if I play the query twice.

Answer (score 1):

[Aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) like `SUM` use the non-aggregated items in the same (`WITH` or `RETURN`) clause as "grouping keys". So, your `WITH` clause is generating a `SommeUnits` value for each distinct `SommeUnits/ReordLevel` combination. And your `CREATE` is being called for each `SommeUnits` value.

This query should work properly (assuming that you want every returned record to have the same `SommeUnits` value):

```
MATCH(p:Product) WHERE p.productName <> "TotalReord"
WITH SUM(p.unitsInStock) AS SommeUnits, COLLECT(p) AS ps
MERGE(t:Product {productName: "TotalReord"})
SET t.unitsInStock = SommeUnits
WITH ps, SommeUnits
UNWIND ps AS p
RETURN p.reorderLevel AS ReordLevel, p.supplierID AS Supplier, SommeUnits
ORDER BY ReordLevel
```

This query uses `MERGE` to avoid creating duplicate "TotalReord" nodes every time you call this query. And the `WHERE` clause filters out the  "TotalReord" node, so that its existing `unitsInStock` value will not be used when calculating the new sum, inflating it.

If you actually want each returned record to have the sum just for that record's `SommeUnits/ReordLevel` combination, you can do this:

```
MATCH(p:Product) WHERE p.productName <> "TotalReord"
WITH SUM(p.unitsInStock) AS u, p.reorderLevel AS r, p.supplierID AS s
WITH COLLECT({u:u, r:r, s:s}) AS data, SUM(u) AS total
MERGE(t:Product {productName: "TotalReord"})
SET t.unitsInStock = total
WITH data
UNWIND data AS d
RETURN d.r AS ReordLevel, d.s AS Supplier, d.u AS SommeUnits
ORDER BY ReordLevel
```

[UPDATED]

Finally, if you want to do the previous query but also get the overall total, this query will show the overall total as the fourth value in each returned record:

```
MATCH(p:Product) WHERE p.productName <> "TotalReord"
WITH SUM(p.unitsInStock) AS u, p.reorderLevel AS r, p.supplierID AS s
WITH COLLECT({u:u, r:r, s:s}) AS data, SUM(u) AS total
MERGE(t:Product {productName: "TotalReord"})
SET t.unitsInStock = total
WITH data, total
UNWIND data AS d
RETURN d.r AS ReordLevel, d.s AS Supplier, d.u AS SommeUnits, total
ORDER BY ReordLevel
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @cybersam. In fact i just realised the photo I shared was not the good one so I replaced it in the original post. The first column is for the ReordLevel, the second one for Suppliers and the third one for SommeUnits.In fact what I actually want to do is to display the SommeUnits for all ReordLevel (as you can see in the photo in the last line), and the SommeUnits for every ReordLevel (example : the sum of all Units for ReordLevel 25, then for 30, etc).  I also tried your second query, but it doesn't work. There's an error asking for a WITH between SET and UNWIND.

Comment: I have now added a `WITH` before the `UNWIND`.

Comment: And I have added another query to also get the overall total (in addition to the SommeUnits per level/supplier combination).